# Angular 2 - How to navigate after Bootstrap?

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

I am trying to navigate to another path in AppComponent on startup and it does not seem to work. In my app.component, I am trying to navigate in my ngOnInit method:

```
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("IN ngOnInit!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        this._router.navigate(["/login"]).then( () => console.log("DONE Navigation!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")).catch(err => console.log("Error!!!!!: " + err));
        console.log("GOING OUT ngOnInit!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
}
```

In my main.ts, I bootstrap the component:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]).then(() => console.log("DONE BOOTSTRAP"));
```

And the console output is:

```
IN ngOnInit!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
GOING OUT ngOnInit!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
DONE Navigation!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
DONE BOOTSTRAP
```

My guess is that the navigation can't be performed because the bootstrap is not complete for the APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS. Are there any events that I can hook onto so that I can call the navigate after the bootstrap is complete? I am on Angular 2 RC4.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment you cannot call the navigate function in the OnInit of the main component.  This is due to a bug cause by this https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/router/src/common_router_providers.ts#L54-L61

There's a issue open open on github: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9101

For the moment, the quick fix would be to put your navigate call in a `setTimout()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: I have chosen this as the answer instead as I need to perform some logic to determine the navigation path.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should give the responsibility of redirection to angular router itself. Add one route which will be responsible for redirecting `''`(blank) to `/login` page, when there is no specific route matched.

```
{
  path: '', //blank will redirectTo `/login`
  redirectTo: '/login',
  pathMatch: 'full'
},
```

Comment: Thanks. That is the behaviour I want!

Comment: @wm_ Glad to help you, Thanks :-)